# In Scala how do you write a init function?

Tags: scala, initialization

For example, in Ruby I can write

```
def initialize(price)
    @Current_price = price
end
```

Comment: The primary _constructor_ in Scala isn't a separate method/function, but is declared as part of the class definition, plus optional logic within the class body.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In scala you write all init in class/trait/object body:

```
class Foo(price: Int) {
  val currentPrice = price
}
```

or simply

```
class Foo(val currentPrice: Int) {

}
```

You can think of class body as of primary constructor method, as DNA said.